# How to calculate $\int \frac{dp}{p\sqrt{p^2 - c^2}}$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find a solution by using Euler-Lagrange, but I'm stuck with this integral.

$$\int \frac{dp}{p\sqrt{p^2 - c^2}}$$

I know I have to use a substitution, but I don't know how.

I'm stuck there and I don't even know if this is good.

$$\int \frac{dp}{p^2\sqrt{1 - \frac{c^2}{p^2}}}$$

Comment: Try $p^2-c^2=x^2$ and multiply and dived by $p$ in the first integral

Comment: I'd go with $x=c/p$.

Comment: You can also try $p=c\sec t$ or, which is harder, $p=c\cosh u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $p=\frac{c}{\sin (x)}\to dp=-c \cot (x) \csc (x)dx$

$x=\arcsin\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)$

Assuming $c>0$

$$\int \frac{dp}{p \sqrt{p^2-c^2}} =\int \frac{- \cot (x) \frac{c}{\sin x}}{\frac{c}{\sin (x)} \sqrt{\left(\frac{c}{\sin (x)}\right)^2-c^2}} \, dx=(*)\\
=\int \frac{-\cot x}{c\cot x}\,dx=-\frac{x}{c}+K=-\frac{1}{c}\arcsin\left(\frac{c}{p}\right)+K$$

$(*)$

$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{c}{\sin (x)}\right)^2-c^2}=\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{\sin^2 (x)}-c^2}=c\,\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin^2(x)}{\sin^2 (x)}}=c\,\sqrt{\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2 (x)}}=\\=c\,\sqrt{\cot^2(x)}=\cot(x)$$

Comment: why you set $$p = \frac{c}{sin(x)}$$

and I don't see how you get cot x to the dominator.

Comment: @proxima I have added some detail. I have chosen $p=\frac{c}{\sin(x)}$ substitution because of the simplification I could get with the differential $dp$. I tried $c \sin(x)$ but I got $-c^2\cos^2(x)$ in the square root, so I changed to $c/\sin(x)$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Assume $ c>0 $ and consider
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2-c^2}}$$

the domain of $ f $ is
$$D=(-\infty,-c)\cup (c,+\infty)$$

$ f $ is continuous at $ D$, then it has antiderivative at each of the intervals of $ D$.

To find the antiderivative at $ (c,+\infty) $, we make the substitution
$$x=c\cosh(u)$$
with
$$x^2-c^2=c^2\sinh^2(u)$$

To find the antiderivative at $ (-\infty,-c)$ , you put $$x=-c\cosh(u)$$

Answer (score 0):

substitute
$$p=c\frac{t+1}{t-1}$$
integral reduces to
$$=-\frac{1}{c}\int{\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}\left( t+1 \right)}dt}=\frac{-2}{c}{{\tan }^{-1}}\left( \sqrt{t} \right)+C=\frac{-2}{c}{{\tan }^{-1}}\left( \sqrt{\frac{p+c}{p-c}} \right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

The substitution applicable to all domains, i.e. both $p<-|c| $ and $p>|c|$, is $t=\sqrt{p^2-c^2}$

$$\int \frac{dp}{p\sqrt{p^2 - c^2}}
=\int\frac{dt}{t^2+c^2}=\frac1{c}\tan^{-1}\frac t{c}
$$